# Yii2 RBAC DbManager error Call to a member function getRole() on null

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I've set up the database etc by having implemented SQL code to set up the tables and the rbac/init script to fill out the roles / permissions.

I have an assign() at user creation but I keep receiving this error on the getRole():

**yii\base\ErrorException Call to a member function getRole() on null**

```
   public function addUser()
{
    if($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();
        $auth_key = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(32);
        $this->password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($this->password);

        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->password = $this->password;
        $user->active = $this->active;
        $user->firstname = $this->firstname;
        $user->lastname = $this->lastname;
        // $user->nickname = $this->nickname;
        $user->datecreated = time();
        $user->auth_key = $auth_key;
        $user->save(false);

        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
        $authorRole = $auth->getRole($this->role);
        $auth->assign($authorRole, $user->getId());

        return $user;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

the $role variable is passed through $_POST along with the other user attributes.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've gone the wrong way about it.

The issue here seems to be that `Yii::$app->authManager` is not set when it should be. This probably means that your main.php configuration file does not contain the correct information.
It should contain the following component:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
];
```

(http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#configuring-rbac-manager)

In the example from the link above **PhpManager** is used but in your case you will want to use **yii\rbac\DbManager**

Doing it this way means that you will only have one loaded manager and will also unlock all action filtering options.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed this by replacing

```
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
```

with

```
$auth = new DbManager;
```

Let me know if this is the wrong way to go about it!